Numbers coming from postgresql as text into powerbi. Facing issue while converting them to number within Power bi
I am fetching data from postgre sql datasource, The keyfigure columns are already in decimal format in postgresql for ex: 0.4. When imported into powerbi I can still see the value as 0.6, but in text format and because i have to perform calculations on it,I want it in form of number. if i convert it to whole number or decimal number within power bi as attached,format changes in power bi, the value appears as 4,00. Please advice if I am missing something or is there another way of getting the expected result.
I converted it to whole number or decimal number within power bi as attachedenter image description here. I expect the value remains 0.4, only the data type needs to be changed to number.

PBI will use your regional settings by default, if you want to convert a number from another local you need to specify it => Change type > using local > Decimal + English US

you can try to convent the data type in power query to see if this works

